# Replace text after nth comma with null

Tags: perl

I have a file with hundreds of SQL insert statements like

```
INSERT INTO dbname.dbo.tbl1(col1, col2, col3,...., coln,...) VALUES (val1, val2, val3,....,valn,....)
```

I need to replace the "valn" with "null" in all the insert statements.

Note: "valn" occurs after the (n-1)th comma.

How can i achieve this in perl?

Comment: Can your data contain quoted string, possibly with commas in them?

Comment: Then you might need to use a CSV module for the parsing, such as [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV_XS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have data that may contain quoted commas, a simple regex will not be enough. You may try and come up with another solution, but the best way may be to use a CSV module such as [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) for that part of your string.

There are a lot of options and functionality to the [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) module, and it can be a little invasive, but it can probably be tweaked to work with your data. Try something along these lines. Be sure to keep backups.

**Usage:** `script.pl input.txt > output.txt`

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;

while (<>) {
    my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({
        binary => 1,
        keep_meta_info => 1,
        allow_whitespace => 1,
    });
    my ($pre, $str, $post) = /^(.* VALUES *\()([^)]+)(\).*)$/;
    $csv->parse($str);
    my @cols = $csv->fields();
    my $n = 4;   # The N-th field
    splice @cols, $n, 1, "null";
    $csv->combine(@cols);
    print $pre, $csv->string(), $post;
}
```

Comment: @ TLP When i have a value val(n+1) with multi line values, i get an error - **splice() offset past end of array at remove-blobs.pl line 20, <INPUT> line 1. Use of uninitialized value $pre in print at remove-blobs.pl line 23, <INPUT> lin e 1.**

For e.g., when i have an input such as 'INSERT INTO dbname.dbo.tbl1(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10) VALUES (null, '2011-10-06 17:09:05.0', 6, '_@xyz.com', 1, null, 19, 12d2d0d0a, 'line 0 line1 line2..', 'xyz@abc.com');

Comment: @nvarchar That input works for me (with n = 4). Do you by chance have empty lines in your input?

Comment: Sorry. I missed the line breaks in the input. The input should have been  **INSERT INTO dbname.dbo.tbl1(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10) VALUES (null, '2011-10-06 17:09:05.0', 6, '_@xyz.com', 1, null, 19, 12d2d0d0a, 'line 0 \n line1 \n line2..', 'xyz@abc.com'); **

Answer (score 1):

`perl -i.bak -pe's/,[^,]+,([^)]+)\)/,NULL,$1)/g' your.sql`